# How to set position of seat dynamically as response

Tags: android, bus

currently i am create bus ticket book application. in this application i want to set seat as came response of webservice .so problem is that if left side one sleeper seat and right side seater seat then how i arrange seat like below image.
currently i am using gridview but i don't know how to achieve.
and how to set all dynamically. please suggest if another layout used.
[image: i want this type of output]

below some code that i used

seatLayout.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >
    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/seatLayoutScroll"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/bottomBarSeatSelection"
        android:background="@color/white" >

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/scrollableLayout"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/seatLegendLayout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="5.0dip"
                android:layout_marginTop="5.0dip"
                android:background="@color/white" >
                <include
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    layout="@layout/bus_seat_indicator_layout" />
            </RelativeLayout>
            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/seatLayoutLowerMain"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_below="@+id/seatLegendLayout"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:paddingBottom="5.0dp"
                android:paddingRight="5.0dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10.0dip">

                <GridView
                    android:id="@+id/gridView1"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/driver"
                    android:layout_margin="4dp"
                    android:horizontalSpacing="10dp"
                    android:verticalSpacing="10dp"
                    android:columnWidth="90dp"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:stretchMode="columnWidth" >
                </GridView>

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:id="@+id/driver"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                    android:layout_marginRight="20.0dp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="5.0dp"
                    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/gridView1"
                    android:background="@drawable/steering_icon"
                    android:orientation="horizontal" >
                </RelativeLayout>
            </RelativeLayout>

            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/seatLayoutUpper"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/seatLegendLayout"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_marginTop="10.0dip"
                android:visibility="invisible" />
        </RelativeLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>
    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/bottomBarSeatSelection"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:background="@color/white" >
        <include
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            layout="@layout/bus_seat_bottom_layout" />
    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Using this i achieve below output

[image: currently i created this type of layout]

but i don't have any idea how to achieve 1st image.

Comment: if anyone give downvote ,please explain why you give so i can care next time that points.

Comment: Most likely you didn't post any code. Some guys on here are jerks and need to know to cool there heels before clicking.

Comment: I think you can use RecyclerView with StaggeredGridLayoutManager

Comment: Are the seats buttons, I would recommend using Relative Layout. Its really easy to use and way better in my opinion than Grid

Comment: Please post your code so we could know how far you're from what you want to achieve.

Comment: ohhk..thank you ..please check my updated question

Comment: please post sample code if possible

Comment: Do you want this to update every x seconds to keep the data base and values up to date?

Comment: no ..here no need to update database...my problem is regarding layout

Comment: did you manage to achieve it,I'm facing same issue 
http://stackoverflow.com/q/39411952/5013923

Comment: @RohitRaich no i am still getting issue

Answer (score 0):

I also have been looking for something, but bit more complex than this. But I think this project will help you out with you current requirements. Check these out :-

[Seat Booking library](https://github.com/varunjohn/Booking-Seats-Layout-Sample) 
 and 
[Bus Seat Booking](https://github.com/TakeoffAndroid/SeatBookingRecyclerView)

Let me know if it helps.

**Update:**

Try my little hack to achieve any kind of layout interaction using SVG image.
To be honest, an interactive seat map development was the most challenging task I have ever had in my development life. But somehow I have done it for an asymmetric seat plan.

Here is my approach to make it workable. See my medium [blog](https://medium.com/@scode43/interactive-svg-image-in-android-app-using-kotlin-and-javascript-6715c16397bb) post. Hope it will help you.