# Spacing Issue while creating bus layout in recycler view Gridlayout manager

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, gridlayoutmanager, staggeredgridlayout

I'm using recycler view with `GirdLayout` Manager for creating bus layout. My problem is with spacing, I'm populating data according to row column.

This is how I'm getting layout:

[image]

This is how I want my layout to be:

[image]

**I want the item at row 3 and column 2 beside sleeper seat at row 2 column 0 like shown in the picture above. How can I remove that space, item should accommodate according to its upper item.**

```
customGridAdapter = new CustomGridViewAdapter(getActivity(), busSeatModel, false, fareCategory, BusSeatLayout.this);
                       RtlGridLayoutManager gridLayoutManager = new RtlGridLayoutManager(getActivity(), busSeatModel.getMaxLowerColumn());
                       seatLayout.setLayoutManager(gridLayoutManager);
                       seatLayout.setAdapter(customGridAdapter);
```

This is my `customGridAdapter` `onBindViewHolder`:

```
public class CustomGridViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<CustomGridViewAdapter.MyViewHolder> {

    Context context;
    BusSeatModel busSeatModel;
    HashMap<Integer, HashMap<Integer, BusSeatItemModel>> data = new HashMap<>();
    LayoutInflater inflater;
    boolean upper;
    HashMap<Integer, BusSeatItemModel> seatLowerModels;
    BusSeatItemModel lowerModel;
    int maxColumn = 0;
    int maxRow = 0;
    BusSeatLayout busSeatLayout;
    int fare;

    public CustomGridViewAdapter(Context context, BusSeatModel busSeatModel, boolean upper, int fare, BusSeatLayout busSeatLayout) {
        this.context = context;
        this.busSeatModel = busSeatModel;
        inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        this.fare = fare;
        this.busSeatLayout = busSeatLayout;
        this.upper = upper;
        if (upper) {
            data = busSeatModel.getBusSeatUpperModels();
            maxColumn = busSeatModel.getMaxUpperColumn();
            maxRow = busSeatModel.getMaxUpperRow();
        } else {
            data = busSeatModel.getBusSeatLowerModels();
            maxColumn = busSeatModel.getMaxLowerColumn();
            maxRow = busSeatModel.getMaxLowerRow();
        }
    }


    @Override
    public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.seatrow_grid, parent, false);

        MyViewHolder myViewHolder = new MyViewHolder(view);

        return myViewHolder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
        try {

            int row = GetRow(position);
            int column = GetCol(position);

            Log.d(" Row Column  ", "" + row + "  " + column);

            seatLowerModels = new HashMap<>();

            if (data.containsKey(row)) {
                seatLowerModels = data.get(row);
                if (seatLowerModels.containsKey(column)) {
                    lowerModel = seatLowerModels.get(column);
                    Log.v(" same fare ", " model fare " + lowerModel.getBaseFare() + " category selected " + fare);
                    if (fare == -1) {
                        Log.v("  fare  is all ", "++++    ");

                        holder.imageItem.setImageResource(lowerModel.getDrawableName(false));

                    } else {
                        Log.v("  fare  is not all ", "");
                        if (lowerModel.getBaseFare() == fare) {
                            Log.v("  fare  is same ", "");
                            holder.imageItem.setImageResource(lowerModel.getDrawableName(false));
                        } else {
                            Log.v("  fare  is diff ", "");
                            holder.imageItem.setImageResource(lowerModel.getDrawableName(true));
                        }
                    }
                    holder.imageItem.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }


    private int GetCol(int pos) {
        int col = pos % (maxColumn);
        return col;
    }

    private int GetRow(int pos) {
        int row = pos / (maxColumn);
        return row;
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return maxColumn * maxRow;
    }


    public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        ImageView imageItem;


        public MyViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);


            imageItem = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.item_image);}
    }
}
```

This is the `recyclerview`:

```
<RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/rlRecycler"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="#ffffff"
            android:gravity="center">

            <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/rvFareCategory"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:background="#ffffff"
                android:paddingBottom="6dip"
                android:paddingTop="8dip"></android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>
        </RelativeLayout>
```

And, seat layout XML:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/item_image"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@null"
    android:padding="4dp"
    android:visibility="invisible"></ImageView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Post your *xml layout* code.

Comment: @jayroider I've updated xml code

Comment: Are these rows added dynamically or using this *layout* itself ?

Comment: these rows are added dynamically depending on the data.
I've passed seatlayout.xml to adapter

Comment: Could you show me the full code for both *Activity* and *Adapter* ?

Comment: @jaydroider I've updated it please check.

Comment: A GridLayoutManager can't help you with that layout. What you're looking for is a StaggeredGridLayoutManager which could be easily  adapted to replicate the layout(I've made a small example here https://gist.github.com/luksprog/230c97dfb00d71141e2f3b5b26699e00), another alternative would be a LinearLayoutManager with different row types(where a row will consist of a big seat + space + 4 small seats).

Comment: @Luksprog your code Working perfectly,Post your code as answer https://gist.github.com/luksprog/230c97dfb00d71141e2f3b5b26699e00

Answer (score 0):

The problem, of course, arises from the fact that your elements don't have the same height. You need to assign different row spans to the elements. I would suggest assigning the taller elements (the ones on the left) a row span of 2 and 1 for the smaller ones.

I think you could do it with a trick like setting your grid layout manager to have a horizontal orientation and use `GridLayoutManager.setSpanSizeLookup(..)` to control the span (since yours is horizontal now, the span would act on rows). This would require you to probably rework the logic of getting your elements from the backing array. The alternative would be I am afraid (as far as I know) to implement your own custom layout manager.

Comment: sorry but i'm completely new with GridLayout Manager, how can i Set span size of depending on the row

Comment: Let's say position 0 needs to span 2 rows and the rest just one:    layoutManager.setSpanSizeLookup(new GridLayoutManager.SpanSizeLookup() {
    @Override
    public int getSpanSize(int position) {
     if (position == 0)
      return 2;
     return 1;
    }
   });

Comment: please check I've changed images for better understanding what i want to achieve

Comment: Looking over this again, I stumbled across `StaggeredGridLayoutManager`. This should work, given you can control the size of your images.

Comment: i tried StaggeredGridLayout but the layout becomes so messy because there's no empty space was left, so column 1 will not be visible

Comment: You can always play with padding and margins for the views, but worst things come, what prevents you from adding invisible views for the space (or use `Space`)?

Comment: row 3 is starting after row 2 bt i want to omit row 3,0 position as there's no item associated with it

Answer (score 0):

I suggest implementing your recycler view item layout as a [TableLayout](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TableLayout.html) or a [GridLayout](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/GridLayout.html), they provide more flexibility in defining row/column spans.

Some useful links:

http://android-pro.blogspot.com.eg/2010/02/table-layout.html
https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/grid.html

Comment: using TableLayout or GridLayout how can i remove that spacing,I tried using Table and GridLayout bt row 3 was starting after row 2 only, i want to somewhat overlap row 3 on row 2 as shown in image.

Comment: I'm not sure but maybe you can try to set the items' layout_gravity to top

Comment: i tried, the layout look same as it, the pic i've shared has gravity top only